# Does killing a session at the database server side also closes the connection and makes the jdbc connection object null?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, connection, connection-pooling

Suppose there is a jdbc code running some CRUD operations. Now, in a particular scenario there happened to be a row lock and the session became blocking to other database sessions.

In this case if the blocking session was killed at the database side what would happen to the corresponding java Connection object? Would that object become null after giving exception? What could be the behaviour if that connection object is used later in the code without placing the checks?

I know that as best practice we should get connection from the pool and close it when finished, but there is quite a lot of legacy code written the other way which will take some time to clean-up.

What would be the answer if the above connection is created through a datasource, managing connection pool, rather than through plain jdbc connection?

Comment: Which database server is this? Not that it is important, it is the JDBC driver that you use, that might matter more.

Comment: The database server is Oracle 10g used through jdbc thin driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever operations are in progress will throw an `SQLException` and any calls to the `Connection.isClosed()` method will return true.  Any subsequent attempts to use the connection object will also throw `SQLException` with the error saying that the connection is closed.

This will not set your connection object to null.  Nothing can do this unless you write explicit code to set the object to null if an exception is thrown or `Connection.isClosed()` returns true.  You would have to do that manually.

Comment: Cavaet - _If_ the driver and/or app/seb server controlling your pool of connections isn't buggy.  I've been caught out on more than one occasion, especially when txns are involved. :(

Comment: Yes, testing this is a good idea.  SQL drivers are not all created equal.

Comment: In such a case what would the app server do? Does it periodically keeps checking the connections it has in pool and replace any faulty ones with fresh connections or just passing along faulty connection?

Comment: You would have to ask the app server that, or find out through experimentation.  The app server may even have settings to adjust this behavior.

Comment: Most app servers have connection pools which allow configuring a bunch of options, how a connection can be idle before it's closed and how to test if a connection is still alive. If you're hanging on to the connection instances (and not closing them - which would result in _returning_ them to the pool), you're out of luck, though.  To make proper use of the pool, get a connection when starting a chunk of work and close it when you're done. Unfortunately, this leads to a bunch of boiler-plate code, which is why for instance Spring's JdbcTemplate exists: http://goo.gl/fT6EU.

Comment: Some drivers, such as the MySQL one, support auto-reconnecting if the connection is lost for some reason and that might be a solution for you if you don't want to refactor: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html